# i want to reduce the length of the edit text

Tags: android, animation

Hi i want to reduce the length of the edittext view to 3/4 of the screen by animation. Help me on this and below is my code to animate. But it does not happen to move. I want to move it from right to left. Help me please thanks in advance

below is my code

```
private void animate() {
    initialLength = etSearchText.getWidth();
    currentLength = initialLength - ibtnSearch.getWidth();
    ScaleAnimation anim = new ScaleAnimation(initialLength, currentLength,0, 0);
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(3000);
    etSearchText.startAnimation(anim);
    initialLength = currentLength;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above code is called in the onCreate method, you'll find that ibtnSearch.getWidth() is equal to 0. Elements only gain a size after the onResume method I believe. Try temporally hardcoding the size of the search button to see if the animation works or not

Also you'll need to change the scale constructor used to change the point of scaling

try `new ScaleAnimation(1, 0.75, 1, 1, 0, 0);` Note that the scaling is done by factor terms, not pixel difference.